# ImportError: no module named uuid in python

Tags: python, uuid, importerror

I am new to python.
when I run a sample code in a one of file using the statement :

```
import uuid
res = uuid.uuid4()
```

It works but in another file as part of a product code, which throws the exception. Any clue why this is happening? It worked other import statements

```
import socket
import sys
```

bash-4.1$ python --version
Python 2.6.6

Comment: can you share snippet of both instances?

Comment: import uuid
import sys





try:
    res = uuid.uuid4()
    ..........

except:
    dumpStack()
    raise

Comment: its just failing the import statement by throwing the exception ImportError: no module named uuid

Comment: That's a really old Python version you're running. Perhaps the interpreter throwing the error is even older - the `uuid` module was introduced in Python 2.5, so if you've still got Python 2.4 running in production, `uuid` wouldn't be available.

Comment: but my production system shows its version as 2.6.6

Comment: bash-4.1$ which python
/usr/bin/python

bash-4.1$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.6.6

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: yes My application internally has python which is old version path pointed.